# How to move a value from a function below in the code, make it global in js?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
$('.fakelink').on('change', function () {
    //date = $(this).val();

    date = '2010-01-24';

});

console.log(date); // Not in console
```

If console.log (date) is moved outside the function, then the console is empty, it turns out that the **date** is not passed down the code outside the function.

How to send the **date** value further down the code from the function?

I just can't beat this script, I didn't work with js at all. I read the recommendations, used the advice, but I could not do anything worthwhile.

Help me, please.

Thank you!

Comment: `.on('change'` means the function will run when there is a change event. The `console.log()` right after *cannot* execute afte rthere was a change event. It will always execute before.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is running asynchronously.
So when your code runs outside the function, it will run before the date value has been defined.
notice that `on.('change'` is changed to `on.('click'` in this example:

```js
let date;

// This function is asynchronous
$('.fakelink').on('click', function () {

    date = '2010-01-24';

});

console.log("This is outside the function: " + date); // This runs first
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="fakelink">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Is in the console :(

Comment: Works only inside a function. This can be seen from your example. There is one conclusion, there must be two. Outputs what is in the function.

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: Not: This is outside the function 2010-01-24...